# enumerateのカスタマイズと空白

Tags: latex

`enumerate`環境をカスタマイズし、以下のようなものを作りました。すると、左側に不自然な余白が生じてしまいます（画像を参照）。検索してみると、`\labelwidth`や`\leftmargin`の値を変更する方法が見つかりましたが、改善はしませんでした。ラベルをむりやり置き換えているのがいけないのか、設定値が悪いのか、原因がわからず、修正できないでいます。なにかうまい方法はないでしょうか。

エンジンはplatex,dvipdfmxです。必要ならばパッケージを追加してもよいですが、なるべく使わず、また、`inheritance`環境の定義側のみの修正で実現できるのが理想です。

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{inheritance}{%
\begin{enumerate}%
  % 
  \labelwidth=0pt%
  \leftmargin=0pt%
  %
  \def\makelabel##1{##1}%\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}% orignal
  \def\labelenumi{\hspace{\value{enumi}em}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Lsh$}}%
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\section{Class BufferedOutputStream}
The class implements a buffered output stream.
By setting up such an output stream,
an application can write bytes to the underlying output stream
without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system
for each byte written.
\subsection*{Inheritance}
\begin{inheritance}
  \item java.lang.Object
  \item java.io.OutputStream
  \item java.io.FilterOutputStream
  \item java.io.BufferedOutputStream
\end{inheritance}
\end{document}
```

[image: compile result]

Comment: 質問文のコードにもコメントアウトされた状態で記述されていますが、 `\llap` を用いることでその余白が消えると思います。`\llap` では何か問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: `\llap`を具体的にどのように使えばよいのでしょうか。コメントアウトしているのは、この部分をそのままつかってもうまくいかなかったためです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最小限のケアですが，次のもので左側の一定のスペースは無くなります：

```
\newenvironment{inheritance}{%
\leftmargini=1em\relax
\begin{enumerate}%
  %
  \labelwidth=1em%
  \advance\labelwidth\labelsep%
  %
  \def\makelabel##1{##1}%
  \def\labelenumi{\hspace{\value{enumi}em}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Lsh$}}%
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

Comment: ご提案の方法で実現できました。参考までに伺いたいのですが、こうした`\leftmargini`などのパラメータについて体系的に述べているオフィシャルな仕様書みたいなものが実はあるのでしょうか。今回の質問でも、そもそも何が調整可能なパラメータなのか不明で、自分では試行錯誤の段階にも至りませんでした。

Comment: "unofficial"と付いていますが，次のものが相当すると思います：“LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual” http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html